# I'm trying to build a 2 step archiver tool for a spreadsheet I'm working on to track inventory problems

Tags: google-sheets

I built a googlesheet that would track errors in our inventory, and then when you toggled a check box it would take that whole row and move it over to an archive sheet so we could keep all that data nicely. That part worked great with this code:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getSheetByName("Maintenance Needed");
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Maintenance Needed" || r.columnStart != 10 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance Done");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

Then I was asked to add a intermediate "in progress" page, where inventory issues that were in progress could be sent, and then also sent to the archive from there. I tried building off of the original code and ended up with:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getSheetByName("Maintenance Needed");
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Maintenance Needed" || r.columnStart != 10 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance Done");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getSheetByName("Maintenance In Progress");
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Maintenance In Progress" || r.columnStart != 10 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance Done");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getSheetByName("Maintenance Needed");
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Maintenance Needed" || r.columnStart != 11 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance In Progress");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

This would only have one function working at a time depending on order. Based on the googling I did, and questions I read here, this didn't work because there can be only one onedit function, which makes sense, but when I tried to name them all their own function and make the onedit function call functions 1, 2, and 3 then nothing would work. I'd really appreciate any help combining these. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to combine all your 3 onEdit functions into 1. You can try this code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() == "Maintenance Needed" && r.columnStart == 10 && r.rowStart != 1){
    const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance Done");
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  }
  else if (src.getName() == "Maintenance In Progress" && r.columnStart == 10 && r.rowStart != 1){
    const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance Done");
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  }
  else if (src.getName() == "Maintenance Needed" && r.columnStart == 11 && r.rowStart != 1){
    const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maintenance In Progress");
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the try, but that doesn't seem to work either. Everyone I talked to has had troubles getting multiple OnEdit functions to work on a sheet. So I think I'm going to use a more manual work around and keep the original archiver as is. I really appreciate the help though!